# why printf doesn't work it shouldn't be 1,00

Tags: bash

the output should be 1.66 but it is 1,00
why?
I install brew findutils but it doesn't help

```
#!/bin/bash
#bc - l
x=$1
y=$2
t=$(echo "$x/$y " | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.2f \n",$1)}')
echo $t
```

---

```
sh script1.bash 5 3
1,00
```

Comment: Don't post links: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I haven't followed your link or looked at your image, but arithmetic in bash is all integers.  There are no floating point values.

Comment: its on mac m1 but in linux its ok

Comment: And now, having looked at your link: why should the output be 1.66?  What inputs are you using?  Get rid of the link, post the code directly in the question, and show the inputs you are using.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I get `1.67`.  The comma in the output suggests perhaps you have a locale issue.  Which version of `bc`?

Comment: the comma, instead of a period, is likely due to your locale; on my system your code generates `1.67` (`bash 4.4.12`, `bc 1.06.95`, `awk 5.1.1`); I'd suggest adding some additional steps to your code to see where things are breaking ... `echo "$x/$y"`, `echo "$x/$y" | bc -l`; also update the question with your `bash`, `bc` and `awk` versions

Comment: @WilliamPursell bc 1.06

Comment: It works on macOS with US locale; does adding an `export LANG=C` as first command of your script fix the issue?

Comment: @Fravadona yes, now it is working, thx. where I can read about this?

Comment: It's a recurrent problem for the `sort` command, but it also applies to most.

Comment: You need to set `LC_NUMERIC=C`, so that `printf` from `awk` formats numbers accordingly to your expected dot decimal.

Comment: As an aside... Is there a reason you are using both `bc` *AND* `awk`? Try `awk -v x=$1 -v y=$2 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f\n", x/y; exit;}' .` and you don't need `bc` or even `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

if u insist on `1.66` instead of `1.67`, try

> ```
> mawk '($++NF=+(__=$(_+=_^=_<_)) ? int(($--_)*(_*=_+=++_*_*_)/__)/_ \
>                                 : "_ERR_DIV_Zero_")^!_' CONVFMT='%.2f' <<< '5 3'
> ```

```
5 3 1.66
```

if u don't mind the `1.67` instead :

> ```
> gawk '($++NF=+(__=$(_+=_^=_<_)) ? ($--_)/__ \
>                                 : "_ERR_DIV_Zero_")^!_' CONVFMT='%.2f' <<< '5 3'
> ```

```
5 3 1.67
```

if u just want a brute-force approach to get a sizable amount of exact digits without arbitrary precision add-ons :

> ```
> {m,g}awk '
>
>  function _____(___,__,_,____) {
>  1  return !+__ \
>     ? "_ERR_DIV_ZERO_" \
>     : int((_+=_^=_<_)^(_+_+_)*((_+=_)+_+_))<=+PREC \
>     ? sprintf("%.f.%0*.f", int(___/__),
>               ____+=____=(_+=++_)*_, int(((___%__)\
>                 * (_+=(_+=_^=_<_)*_*_)^____)/__))  \
>     : sprintf(("%.f.")(_="%0"(____=______(__))".f")\
>                     (_=(_)(_)(_=(_)(_)_)) (_=(_)_)_,
>       int((___=int(___))/(__=int(__))), 
>       int((_=(___%__)*(___=int((_+=\
>          (_+=_^=_<_)*_*_)^____) ) )/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>       int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>                             int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__),
>                             int((_=_%__*___)/__), int((_=_%__*___)/__))
>  }
>  function ______(____,_,__,___) {
> 1    ___=(__+=(\
>       __=_+=_^=_<_)*_*_)^(++_+_*_+_)*_*_+(_=_<_)
>
> 8    while((____*=__)<___) { ++_ }
>      return +_
>  }
>  ($++NF=_____($(_+=_^=_<_), $++_))^!_' CONVFMT='%.20g' FS='[ ]' \
>       OFS='\f\r\t' ORS='\n\n' <<< ' 8777777777777777 23456789'
> ```

```
 8777777777777777
 23456789
 374210544.238504980370501691429291536876594660931639023567974286676
 6632039875534541407180667396547754255708230141815233107992743593336
 6668387561485930576431411818557092362471265781518519009571173616303
 57846506612648474
```

output from `gnu-bc` for the same division ::

> ```
> echo 'scale = 208; 8777777777777777 / 23456789' | bc -l
> ```

```
 gnubc:

 374210544.238504980370501691429291536876594660931639023567974286676
 6632039875534541407180667396547754255708230141815233107992743593336
 6668387561485930576431411818557092362471265781518519009571173616303
 57846506612648474
```

Comment: This answer solves the problem for OP but does not answer their question.

Comment: @blami : because `OP` uses a rather inefficient approach of making a shell script call `bc` then call `awk` and all that. to make it simple, then just `eval 'gawk -v PREC=65536 -Mbe '\''($++NF = sprintf("%.100f", ($(_^=__)) / ($++_)))^__'\'' <<< "5 3" '    
5 3 1.6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667`